# How to get image through localhost in browser url section

Tags: sql, angular, .net-core

how do i get image in localhost using angular.

like(http://localhost:0000/(folder name)/(image name))

my image stores in project directory and also in sql database.

i see so many code but it doesn't work with my code.

Comment: Mind if we also see many code? Show what have you tried so far so we could understand where is the problem? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-images-in-angular2/

Comment: after a long time, i found the result, the solution is, i have to add a wwwroot folder in my visual studio project then i get the image in localhost. by the way thanks for your time i am currently using visual studio 2019 thats why ifaced that issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store static content in `assets` folder.

Then access it with: http://localhost:0000/assets/(folder name)/(image name)

Comment: after a long time, i found the result, the solution is, i have to add a wwwroot folder in my 
visual studio project then i get the image in localhost. by the way thanks for your time.